# No module named AppOpener

Tags: python

I am just trying to open apps using python and i am using AppOpener. While it seems pretty simple in online and all, by just importing and using like this

```
from AppOpener import open
open("google chrome")
```

it seems to show me the error

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
> "C:/Users/ansha/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/openn.py",
> line 1, in 
> from AppOpener import open
> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppOpener'**

I can use AppOpener from cmd tho. Do u guys have any solution?

```
from AppOpener import open
open("google chrome")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
> "C:/Users/ansha/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/openn.py",
> line 1, in 
> from AppOpener import open
> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppOpener'**

Comment: 1) you shouldn't be using global packages. Use venv or whatever. 2) Do you have the module installed for python3.10?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **VS CODE**?? , if you are then, you must **install AppOpener though terminal**  (I guess..)

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

This will print the **python path** that your IDE is using ✌️

Answer (score -1):

Did you install AppOpener?

`pip install AppOpener`